# Flash projector fails to load local XML on XP

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4, projector

A very simple case:

- There's a Flash EXE projector
- There's a XML file in the folder relative to the projector, data/menu.xml
- Application is launched on a Windows XP box

On one of the XP machines **XML fails to load** over some awkward reason. In most environments it works fine. The same app runs well on all Macs tested.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was the rights issue with loading XML from a subdirectory so the case was resolved by bringing XML to a root level alongside the projector EXE.

Otherwise there should have been a configuration made on each client for the trusted file locations similarly to resolving [regular sandbox issue](http://tekkie.flashbit.net/flash/as/fixing-the-security-sandbox-issue-in-fdt-4-milestone-2)s.